How to return Response Codes for Apex Rest Class
I am new to webhook class. I am trying to expose the apex class to external system to do post operation in salesforce. The external system I am exposing is the authorize.net and according to them I have to return the "HTTP 200 status code"
Here's the screenshot of API documentation.

Here's the debug from my code:
RestContext.response ### RestResponse:[headers={}, responseBody=null, statusCode=null]

RestContext.statusCode again ### 200

Am I returning the status code correctly? Thank you.
@RestResource(urlMapping='/test/*')
global with sharing class WebHookHandler {
 
    @HttpPost
    global static Integer somePost(){
        RestRequest requestContext = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse responseContext = RestContext.response;
        string requestBody = RestContext.request.requestBody.tostring();
        system.debug('RestContext.response ### '+RestContext.response);
        responseContext.statusCode = 200;
        system.debug('RestContext.statusCode again ### '+responseContext.statusCode);
        return responseContext.statusCode;
        }
    }//end of handle post


The return value of the method call will be serialized. That means that, over the wire, your response will end up looking like:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 3
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
<<more headers here>>

200

This is probably not what you want to do. You'll need to refer to the documentation for the webhook you're trying to process for more details.
You should return a value for the response body that matches the expected response for the webhook. That will look something like this:
@HttpPost
global static void somePost(){
    RestRequest requestContext = RestContext.request;
    RestResponse responseContext = RestContext.response;
    string requestBody = RestContext.request.requestBody.tostring();
    responseContext.statusCode = 200;
    responseContext.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('success'); // or whatever they expect
}//end of handle post


Thank you sfdx for quick response. I am still confused on what needs to go in responseBody. I have updated the image of what they are asking. Should I be just adding responseContext.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('HTTP 200 OK') ? Is it possible for me to check for correct response anywhere to see I am returning correct stuff?

@calo I don't think it matters what responseBody you use, if you use any at all. The HTTP1/1 200 OK is a header, and does not belong in the body, though. However, I also think that Salesforce might silently switch the 200 to a 204 if you don't include a body. ... I guess just try it and see? I couldn't find anything in the documentation about the response body, just that you need a 200 response.

So all it's needed is responseContext.statusCode = 200? Or Do I have to send "HTTP 200'? Thanks for looking at the documentation. Is this correct way to return at the end of the class ? return responseContext.statusCode;

@calo You don't need to return anything. The RestContext.response variable is used to formulate the response. Again, given I can't find much on the actual return value, you may as well just return some kind of string, it doesn't matter. The only thing that matters is response.StatusCode must be 200.

Thank you! You are lifesaver!
